# Read URL by JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have function that return the name of the table with this URL `('..../default/call/json/mytables')`

But I don't know how I can say it to my function `getTable()` to return the value of my URL.

---

```
    function getTable(){
        return '.../default/call/json/mytables';
    }

    console.log(getTable());


    function initialize() {
            var $newDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','chart_div');
        $('#reportingContainer').append($newDiv);
  // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
  // Specify that we want to use the XmlHttpRequest object to make the query.
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('/datasource?table='+getTable());

  // Optional request to return only column C and the sum of column B, grouped by C members.
  query.setQuery('select zone_name, sum(cost) group by zone_name');

  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(drawChart);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the URL that you're trying to get contain only JSON? If so, a simple jQuery GET request can do what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, it'a only JSON. could you Explain mors?

Comment: @Luke Evers could you give me un exemple?

Comment: Yes, [I've added one below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808465/read-url-by-json/17808919#17808919).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only JSON in the URL that you're returning, try something like this:

```
function getTable() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../default/call/json/mytables',
        success: function(response) {
            // You can manipulate the variable response
            // Success!
            return response;
        },
        error: function(response) {
            // You can manipulate the variable response
            // Errors!
        }
    });
}
```

Or if you'd like to do something even shorter, you can do it this way:

```
function getTable() {
    return $.get('../default/call/json/mytables');
}
```

I prefer the ajax method, but either work! I hope that answered what you were asking.

Comment: thanks a lot :) but you know, now i have another error like this   " Error in query: Internal error Failed to execute SQL query. mySQL error message: Table 'XXX.undefined' doesn't exist " do you have any idea? and this is my query " 'http://localhost:8000/XXX_reporting/default/call/json/mytables', "